# Is It Legal to Use Groups API for Displaying Public Group Posts on My Personal Website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

As an admin of several public Facebook groups, I'm looking into the possibility of showcasing posts from these groups on my personal website using Facebook's Graph API.
It's important for me to comply with legal and Facebook's policy guidelines.

Does Facebook's policy allow for using its Graph API to access and display public group data on an external website?
Additionally, are there any legal considerations or restrictions in this regard?

Notably, I do not intend to retrieve or display any usernames or profile photos on my site.
My site will have a link to the original facebooks posts and my users can get the facebook username just throw the facebook link.Any insights, experiences, or resources on this matter would be highly valued.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I searched the web a lot without clear answer